# How to test nested libraries locally in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have two component in my library named ***lib-questionnaire*** and ***lib-choices***.

The component ***lib-questionnaire*** uses ***lib-choices*** like this in its html file.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <lib-choices
       [name]="name"
       [id]="id"
       [choices]="choices">
    </lib-choices
  </div>
</div>
```

But since I have changes in my ***lib-questionnaire*** like adding another *Input* for example like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <lib-choices
       [name]="name"
       [id]="id"
       [multipleChoices]=true
       [choices]="choices">
    </lib-choices
  </div>
</div>
```

The added *Input* which is *[multipleChoice]* is not currently declared in the ***lib-choices*** in the production but I've declared it in my local.

I've tried building first the ***lib-choices*** locally, then building the ***lib-questionnaire*** but it fails to build since it cannot accept my new input since it is not yet implemented in the production.

My question is how to build both of my components in the library locally?

Comment: Are these two components in two different library modules? As per your question they are both in same library. Then why and how are you building these individually?

Comment: Yes, they have different modules. In building, I use the command *ng build @lib/questionnaire* and *ng build @lib/choices*.

Comment: I've use the command *ng g library @lib/component -p lib --entry-file /public-api* for building both of the components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link), which creates a symlink in your dependant apps/libraries node_modules directory. It involves:

- Run `npm link` in the local library
- Run `npm link @local-library-name` in the host application
- But make sure you set "preserveSymlinks": true on your host applications/libraries angular.json file:

```
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
      "options": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
        "tsConfig": "projects/button/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "project": "projects/button/ng-package.json"
      }
    },
```

In your case you can do the following:

- Get into `@lib/choices` directory and run `npm link`
- Get into `@lib/questionnaire` directory run `npm link @lib/choices` and do your build. You can also do `npm link` here so that you can use it in the host application by using `npm link @lib/questionnaire`

Update:

In angular 14, you would also have to update `tsconfig.json` of your host app:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
}
```

Comment: Should I still do the *ng build @lib/component* and also update my package.json for the file path? I tried doing the *npm-link* and checked my angular.json for both the library and host application which has both "preseverSymlinks" set as true. But the host application is not getting my changes for both.

Comment: What do you think about running `npm link` in the `dist` folder of the local library?